# Doubt in vertex connectivity less than edge connectivity

Tags: graphs

Sir i recently started graph theory. I understood the reason why edge connectivity is less than min degree(remove all vertices incident to min degree vertex). I have doubt in 2nd part of proof when given graph is not complete graph. how to prove here vertex connectivity less than edge connectivity?
confused here. Pls clarify my doubt

Comment: Cross posted on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227679/doubt-in-vertex-connectivity-less-than-edge-connectivity-proof).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You mention "2nd part of proof" but not what proof you're actually looking at, or what theorem it's meant to prove, for example. Are you asking, specifically: **why is vertex connectivity always less than or equal to edge connectivity**?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. Since this is a mathematics question, I'm closing it here.

Comment: @Discretelizard sir i am new to theseforums. I did not get any reply there and so i posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, so this is the specific question I'm answering:

> Why is the vertex connectivity of a graph always less than or equal to its edge connectivity?

If that's wrong, please let me know in the comments or edit the question.

---

The vertex connectivity of a graph is defined as *the smallest number of vertices you can delete to make the graph no longer connected*. The edge connectivity is the same, except substitute "edge" for "vertex".

So, let's take a graph $G$, and say its edge connectivity is $e_c$. This means, by definition, there's some set of edges $E_c$, such that deleting all those edges will make $G$ no longer connected, and $|E_c| = e_c$ (there are $e_c$ different edges in the set).

Let's assume that the vertex connectivity is greater than $e_c$. I'm going to show that this leads to a contradiction.

Let's go through $E_c$ and take one arbitrary endpoint from each edge. (At random, or always take the tail, etc, doesn't matter.) Call this new set of endpoints $V_{Ec}$. There's one for each edge, so there are $e_c$ total.

Deleting a vertex includes deleting every edge that touches it, so deleting every vertex in $V_{Ec}$ must delete every edge in $E_c$. Thus, deleting every vertex in $V_{Ec}$ makes the graph disconnected.

But we only deleted $e_c$ different vertices! If the vertex connectivity is any larger than $e_c$, we have a contradiction—since the vertex connectivity is the *smallest* number of vertices you can delete to disconnect the graph. And we just showed you can do it with fewer.

Therefore, the vertex connectivity can never be larger than the edge connectivity.

Comment: Sir thank you. this is perfectly fine. But in some other proof (pls see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2109&v=gx8YqmRCmMY at 35.14) professor here takes 2 cases - if graph is complete and another case - graph is not complete. I did not understand second case here.

Comment: can you pls enlighten me if possible?

Comment: @NascimentodeCos This proof works regardless of whether the graph is complete or not.

Comment: sir, in 1st case,professor takes first edge connectivity set [S, S'] where every vertex in S has edge with every vertex of S'(here i am thinking this case as complete graph). Here i understood. In case 2, professor takes some vertices in S have no adjacent edges with some vertex in S'. This case i did not understand.

Comment: My thinking, say some edges are not there between S and S'. I remove only those edges that do from S to S'. Now will the graph gets disconnected right? now i take either of 2 vertices on those edges. That makes vertex connectiviyt set cardinality = edge connectivity set cardinlity. But why professor takes T? i did not understand the intuition behind T. Pls tolerate my ignorance and elaborate in your free time

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Again, look at the answer I posted. I gave you a proof that works regardless of whether the graph is complete or not. I don't know what your professor meant by "T".

Comment: Sir i understood your proof. It is simple and to the point. I will take a gap and think about the other proof again. By the way Tq  for the inputs. Even some nternet sources are also using this kind of proof( for ex., https://www.imsc.res.in/~vikram/DiscreteMaths/2011/connectivity.pdf).

Comment: @NascimentodeCos That proof is basically being more rigorous about the "one arbitrary endpoint of each edge" thing.